# URL to user's documents directory is empty

Tags: swift

I've written this helper function to get the URL of the user's documents directory:

```
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let path = documentsURL[0]
        return path
    }
```

When stepping through this function with the debugger, path is always an empty URL:
[debugger view of path value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YNMX.png)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try using `po path` in the console

Comment: Ah, thanks! That output `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E10EC9E1-97C9-46C5-976B-50EA14481B43/Documents/`. Once I write a file to that location, will I be able to view in the "Files" app on an iOS device?

Comment: `let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`

Comment: @GregSchloemer No. You would need to set your info.plist property `Supports opening documents in place` to `YES` to make your app be listed inside Files app directory `onMyPhone`